# Firebase Storage: How to reduce requests? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm developing a chat app with Firebase. Am currently still in development phase.

Profile pictures of test users are uploaded to Firebase Storage, and are downloaded in the home screen (with all the pictures). I realized that with that I very quickly used up storage download requests (easily hit 3,000 requests in one night, and hit the free plan quota!).

What are some best practices I could use to minimize download requests? Just to be sure I'm doing it right - I'm sending a GET request to the Firebase Storage url directly: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...` to download the image. Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions that might help:

1. Cache your images! If you keep requesting the same images over and over again over the network, that's going to use up your quota pretty fast. Not to mention your user's battery and network traffic. After you retrieve an image from the network, save it locally, and then the next time you need an image, look for it locally before you make another network request. Or consider using a library like [PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage) that does most of the work for you. (Both on the retrieving as well as the caching side)
2. Consider uploading smaller versions of your image if you think you might be using them often. If your chat app, for instance, saves profile pictures as 1024x768 images, but then spend most of its time showing them as 66x50 thumbnails, you're probably downloading a lot of data you don't need. Consider saving both the original image and a thumbnail, and then grabbing the larger one only if you need it.

Hope that helps...